# How can i prevent page reload on form submit angular 7

Tags: button, submit, angular7, reload

I am not familiar with Angular .Am facing a problem with submit button .When i click on button where type is submit it is reloading the complete page .Instead of calling my service API.

Even i added (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()" on form tag and in Button click method also i tried with event.preventDefault() . But didn't worked.

Please check my below code

```
<form  #createForm="ngForm" class="login-form text-center" (ngSubmit)="Update()" (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()">
       <table cellpadding="5" class="mx-auto">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label class="white pr-2" for="email" autofocus>Email</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input name="email" id="email" type="text" [(ngModel)]="email" required  #name="ngModel"class="d-inline-block w-100" >
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class="text-left">

                <button class="d-inline-block text-left lh-100" id="login" type="submit"  [disabled]="!createForm.form.valid">Change Password
                 </button>&nbsp;
                 <button class="float-right lh-100" style="background-color:grey" [routerLink]="'/login'" >Back to Login</button>

             </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
```

Here is my .ts code . button update method

```
Update()
  {

   this.userservice.changePassword(this.email).pipe(first())
    .subscribe(
        data => 
        {
            if(!data.message)
            {
              this.errorMsg = data.message;
            }
           else 
            {
              this.errorMsg = data.message;
            }
        },
        error => {
          this.errorMsg = error.Message;
        });

  }
```

Here is the service code

```
 changePassword(EmailId: string) {

        return  this.http.get<Validations>(`${environment.apiUrl}/User/SendMail?userName=` + EmailId+`&subject=`+''+`&message=`+''+`&mailType=`+'changepassword');
    }
```

app.module.ts File

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { GridModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';

import { LoginComponent } from './common/login/login.component';
import { ForgotPwdComponent } from './common/forgotPwd/forgotPwd.component';
import { BlankComponent } from './common/blank/blank.component';
import { ResetComponent } from './common/reset/reset.component';





@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ForgotPwdComponent,
    ResetComponent,
    BlankComponent,


  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,

    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    GridModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,


  ],
```

please suggest how can i prevent page reload after submit button and execute my service call.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If there is an error in **onSubmit** then it will get refreshed. So make sure you have imported
**FormsModule** and **ReactiveFormsModule** from **@angular/forms** in your respective **module.ts** or in **app.module.ts**

app.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { HeroFormComponent } from './hero-form/hero-form.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroFormComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Ya i have imported import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; in app.module.ts

Comment: can u share your app.module.ts  ??

Comment: also check for  ReactiveFormsModule is imported or not if not the import it

Comment: you missed ReactiveFormsModule  please add it

Comment: Now Added ReactiveFormsModule and tested code but same reload problem

Comment: your code is working fine I have tested here  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yghuby. additional for "Back To login " button set type as Button.

Comment: oK Thank you so much for the support .

Comment: Thank you, I've been stuck for hours and even chatGPT doesn't know the answer.

Answer (score 7):

If you add `FormsModule` to `app.module.ts`, as follows:

```typescript
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  ...
})
```

and restart it with `ng serve` (if the `ng serve` process is running, then stop it and run again), then this problem will be fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Root cause, there is an **error in form**.

This could happen due to multiple reasons, here is a scenario I encountered hope it helps to someone.

*In my angular 12 app*

I used like

```
<div [formGroup]="testForm" (ngSubmit)="save()">
```

Instead it should be

```
<form [formGroup]="testForm" (ngSubmit)="save()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Return false with (submit) prevent reload.

Answer (score 0):

Change the type property of button from submit to button or any other one.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 12, it is `[FormGroup]` that listens to the submit event:

> The FormGroup directive listens for the submit event emitted by the form element and emits an ngSubmit event that you can bind to a callback function. [see doc.](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

So you have to have:

- a `[FormGroup]` on your `<form>` element
- `(ngSubmit)` and a component method
- `ReactiveFormsModule` loaded
- a public `FormGroup` property on your component class, preferably with some properties in it matching the form inputs

Answer (score 0):

make sure to use (ngSubmit)="signIn()" directly from the openning form tag instead of submitting through a button or an href tag...find my own example below..this might help someone

if you use button if will reload the page after failed submission.

```
                <form
                [formGroup]="signInForm"
                #signInNgForm="ngForm"
                (ngSubmit)="Update()">
```